# Install neo4j 3.0.1 in ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

I try to install the latest version of neo4j(3.0.1) in my ubuntu 14.04
server,

But if the version is not Neo4j 2.1.6 I can't find the "neo4j-server.properties" and can't restart the service "neo4j-service".

There is any changing at the installation process ? (the [resource](http://www.codiply.com/blog/standalone-neo4j-server-setup-on-ubuntu-14-04/) i'm using for installation)

Answer (score 0):

Use `#service neo4j start` instead of neo4j-service
the properties and config files are in /etc/neo4j

Good luck